# Find the missing shape in this grid

Tags: sequence

[image]

What shape should go in the empty square?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> [image: upper right triangle]

Because:

> To get the third square, flip the first square vertically and XOR it with the second square on the row below (wrapping around back to the top row if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Nothing goes in the empty square.

Explanation:

> For each row, the third square is the path difference between a modified second and first square. You modify the first square by flipping it across the X-axis. You modify the second square by reflecting across the main diagonal and finding the union of the two shapes.

Answer (score 0):

> [image: Square]

Reasoning

> The final column is always a combination of the previous two, in multiples, Inverse.. Not as obvious in the second row as both shapes are rotation (<90deg in segments of 90deg) agnostic, however with the square.. It's result is always a square..

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing

My Reasoning:

> Working horizontally through each row it is the 2nd shape shrunk horizontally by 50% and then mirrored across a vertical line in the middle of the square. The first shape is then cut out of the result of the shrinking and mirroring. A Square shrunk by 50% and then mirrored would be the same size as the original squareso the image from position 1 would fit directly over it leaving a blank image.

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

> a circle

Explanation:

> Counting the times that the triangle pokes the roof, from left to right, we get this sequence: 
>  010  / 100 / 101 
>  And using this to determine what goes where:
>  1 - Ball, 
>  10 - Square, 
>  0 - Nothing 
>  It creates a pattern that could be interpreted like this:
>  **Row 2**: Combines them like this 
>  01+0 / 10+0 / 10+1 
>  Ball & nothing, Square & nothing, Square & ball. 
>  **Row 3**: Only counts the last number 
>  01+0 / 10+0 / 10+1 
>  Nothing. Nothing. ball